# Handling SVG in Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, svg

I am looking for some resources about that. I have svg kind of map file and I would like to put on it some pushpins.

Any tutorials available in this subject?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a speculative route for you.
Use INKSCAPE to convert the SVG to XAML.
See if it will then render in Expression Blend.
The put your pushpins onto the XAML canvas.
Might work....